# Duda con libreria modal

Tags: javascript, modal

```js
const mmv = (a = null) => {
  let b = document.querySelectorAll(".click").forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
      const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
      console.log("Se ha clickeado el id " + id);
      if (id) {
        let element = document.getElementById("sd");
        element.innerHTML = `esto es ${id}`;
      }
    });
  });
};
mmv()
```

```html
    <p id="sd">Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>
   

    <div id="si1" class="click">div 1</div>
    <div id="si2" class="click">div 2</div>
    <div id="si3" class="click">div 3</div>
    <div id="si4" class="click">div 4</div>
    <div id="si5" class="click">div 5</div>
    <div id="si6" class="click">div 6</div>
    <div id="si7" class="click">div 7</div>
    <div id="si8" class="click">div 8</div>
    <div id="si9" class="click">div 9</div>
    <div id="si10" class="click">div 10</div>
    <div id="si11" class="click">div 11</div>
    <div id="si12" class="click">div 12</div>
    <div id="si13" class="click">div 13</div>
    <div id="si14" class="click">div 14</div>
    <div id="si15" class="click">div 15</div>
```

Quiero que lo que cambia en p#sd tambien cambie dentro de un modal de esta libreria:

```
<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
```

Pero lo que me hace es que en ves de cambiar cada vez que hago click en en alguno de los id no cambia mas que en el de la primera vez a diferencia que si lo dejo afuera del modal si lo hace como muestro en el ejemplo, que podria hacer?

Comment: Podrías explicarte mejor, no termino de entender bien el problema, me hago una idea pero me confunde un poco.

Comment: Si tenés varios modales, entonces cada modal debe tener una ID diferente para mostrar ahí lo quieres. Al hacer click en cada número, escribe esa ID de ese click en el modal (ID) con attr

Comment: Deberías compartir el ejemplo con el modal para ver por que no te funciona cuando lo colocas dentro del modal